# Media Icons Not Showing

Tags: sitecore-client

In `Sitecore 9.2`, I am not seeing any icons. Path of every icon are like `src="/-/temp//iconcache/apps/48x48/pencil.png.aspx"`. when i remove `"/-"` and `".aspx"` from DOM then icon appears. I clean up databases and rebuild link DBs and checked the **addAspxExtension** attribute is also set to **false** in **sitecore.config**.
Please let me know if someone faced such an issue or if someone has the solution for it.

[image]

Comment: did you try by deleting the temp/iconcahe folder? you may reset IIS after that.

Comment: Check the permissions on the `/temp` folder under the root website folder. IIS needs to be able to modify and write files and folders, your permissions may be set incorrectly.

Comment: Didn't mention that earlier, website is hosted on Azue Paas, so it does not require permission to folders

Comment: I am also facing similar issue in sitecore 9.2 Azure Paas instance. Any solution for issue. Thanks

Comment: Please check if you have the following handler in your web.config:   <add verb="*" path="sitecore_icon.ashx" type="Sitecore.Resources.IconRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel" name="Sitecore.IconRequestHandler"/>